# How to use Android Project1 (apk) class in Android project2 (apk), if both the application share User ID and signed by same key?

Tags: android

Suppose Project P1 have A.java class needed in Project P2. Both the Project P1 and P2 are unique application and have android:sharedUserId= "com.example" and signed by same key.
Question: How to create object of A.java Present in P1, in project P2 project ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible with APKs. Define a common module which can be integrated by both apps. Or think about IPC, using e.g Intents, ContentProvider, ...

Comment: Check out IPC mechanism. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740324/what-are-the-ipc-mechanisms-available-in-the-android-os  or http://codetheory.in/android-interprocess-communication-ipc-messenger-remote-bound-services/

Comment: You can't use class from other application. All you can do to share some business logic between apks is https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: @ this link --> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid, what does this mean "Application with the same user ID can access each other's data"