# How can I get information created in another application?

Tags: java, android-intent, android-activity

I want to send the user from application 1 to application 2 by pressing a button. In application 2, the user performs an action (for example, writes text), then he clicks the button and the text is sent to application 1.

I know that there is a certain "Getting a result from an activity", but I could not figure out how it works. I also found examples on YouTube where similar actions are performed, but inside one application. How can this be done using different applications?

Comment: I think it is called IPC, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/21630055/175554

Answer (score 0):

You can launch an `Activity` using `startActivityForResult()`. The `Activity` that you launch does not necessarily need to be in the same application. When that `Activity` calls `setResult()` and then `finish()`, the information that was passed in `setResult()` will be returned to your original `Activity` in the method `onActivityResult()`.

I'm sure that you can find some tutorials about how to use `startActivityForResult()`.